Why does the ICC differ when comparing multilevel models (log transformations vs regular scale) of the outcome variable in R using lme4?
I'm currently working on a multilevel modeling project in R utilizing the lme4 package. The primary aim of the research is to assess the relative importance of between-family and within-family variance in explaining income differences among individuals. By examining the Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC), I seek to quantify the proportion of total income variance attributed to differences between families compared to differences within families.
To conduct this analysis, I generated a synthetic dataset consisting of 80 observations nested within 40 families. Each observation includes income and age variables, with individuals assigned to different families. Subsequently, I fitted four distinct multilevel models:
A model utilizing the original income scale (income).
A model employing the logarithmically transformed income scale (logincome).
Despite utilizing the same dataset, I've observed discrepancies in the ICC values across these models. This inconsistency is unexpected, as I believed the ICC should remain invariant to transformations of the outcome variable's scale.
Below is the code snippet I used to generate the dataset and fit the models:
library(lme4)
set.seed(123)

n <- 80 # number of observations 
n_families <- 40 # number of groups (families)

# Level-1 Variable (individual incomes)
income <- rnorm(n, mean = 40000, sd = 10000)

# Level-2 Variables (family effects)
family_id <- rep(1:n_families, each = n/n_families) # Family belonging
family_effect <- rnorm(n_families, mean = 0, sd = 5000) # Family-effect on income

# Assigning family effects to individual incomes based on family_id
income <- income + family_effect[family_id]

# Creation of dataframe
data <- data.frame(income = income, age = age, family_id = factor(family_id))
data$logincome <- log(data$income)


# Fitting multilevel models using lmer
model_regular_scale <- lmer(income ~ 1 + (1 | family_id), data = data)
model_log <- lmer(logincome ~ 1 + (1 | family_id), data = data)


# Summary of models
summary(model_regular_scale)
summary(model_log)
summary(model_10)

# Calculation of ICC values
icc_regular_scale <- 5518713/(5518713 + 91636300)
icc_log_scale <- 0.003098/(0.003098 + 0.058133)

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the ICC values differ between the log-transfored-model and the non-scaled-model. Is there a potential issue with the estimation process or interpretation of the results? Thank you for your assistance!
